# Git list files plus their modifications

Tags: git

For a given commit, I can list all the files affected by doing:

```
$ git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <hash>

file1.cpp
file2.cpp
file3.cpp
```

But what I'm after, is to see the modified/deleted/added tag such as:

```
M file1.cpp
D file2.cpp
A file3.cpp
```

Is there a format that can do this?
Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-status <hash>
```